# Slicing in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I saw a piece of code as following:

```
a = np.zeros((10,10,10))
b = a[:,:,::-1]
```

b is the same as a. What is the purpose of that slicing?

Comment: That is basically reversing the order of elements along the last axis. You won't notice the difference as you are using it on an array of all zeros. Try a random array.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to answer definitively "what is the purpose" with such a small code example.  Here's my guess:

After the code snippet, `a` and `b` are different views *into the same data array.*  Since Python passes objects by reference, If you assign values into `b`, those same values appear in `a`, but with the last index reversed.  If you have a data set and a function, but you want to process the data as if the last data index were reversed, passing `b` rather than `a` into that function effectively operates on `a`, but with the final index reversed.

The salient point is: You can manipulate the contents of `a` by operating on the contents of `b`, but the order of operation is reversed in the last axis.

For example, sorting `b` in ascending order on the last index actually sorts `a` in descending order on the last index.  Here's a simplified example:

```
a = np.rand(4, 2)
a[:, 0] = [4, 2, 1, 3]
b = a[::-1, :]
```

`a` has its first column unsorted, `b` has the same data in the reverse  order.

```
b.sort(axis=0)
```

Now, the contents of `b` are sorted in ascending order on the first column, and the contents of `a` are sorted on the first column but in descending order.